# Swift: Button round corner breaks contraints

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, rounded-corners

I have a tableview with custom cell loaded via xib and in that cell I have status button which bottom right corner should be rounded. The button has constraints Trailing/Leading/Bottom space to superview=0 and height=30.

[image]

Without rounding it is working perfectly, as soon as I round one corner for example bottom right the constraints breaks

```
self.btnStatus.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomRight], radius: 7.0, borderWidth: nil, borderColor: nil)
```

[image]

Some guys here suggesting to call layoutSubviews() but it didn't helped me.

To be more specific I've created simple project where you can have a look into whole project.

**Correct Link**

[ButtonRoundCorner.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppf39a9zqh2sx2w/CustomCellRoundCorners.zip?dl=0)

Comment: What errors are being given about the breaking constraint?

Comment: Without looking at your code, if it breaks constraints, just place it inside a `UIView` and give that container `UIView` the constraints. The constraints won't care what's inside the view, rounded corners or not.

Comment: @benjiiiii: no error at all, just button is not aligned...

Comment: @sconewolf: Already tried it out as well, same result :(

Comment: Are you using a 3rd-party script to round that one corner is it something you wrote?

Comment: @mihatel so with unrounded corners the button is in the right location - with the corners rounded it moves the button to a different location?

Comment: @sconewolf: no, you can have a look into the example, it is extension few lines of code

Comment: @benjiiiii: correct !

Comment: Create a GitHub Gist with your code.

Comment: have you tried set maskToBounds = true?

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht: yes!, didn't helped either.

Comment: @sconewolf: it is available via dropbox, if you have an issue I can send it to you, github is not an option for me, sorry.

Comment: @mihatel - your "dropbox" link is wrong... you have to select "Share" and then create a link.

Comment: @DonMag: my bad, thanks for pointing out
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppf39a9zqh2sx2w/CustomCellRoundCorners.zip?dl=0

Comment: @mihatel - take a look at my answer. I think you'll find it a more reliable approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get more reliable results by subclassing your button and placing your "rounding" code by overriding its `layoutSubviews()` function.

First, if you want to add a border, you don't want to add multiple "border sublayers" ... so change your `UIView` extension to this:

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, borderWidth: CGFloat?, borderColor: UIColor?) {
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath

        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true

        if (borderWidth != nil && borderColor != nil) {

            // remove previously added border layer
            for layer in layer.sublayers! {
                if layer.name == "borderLayer" {
                    layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                }
            }

            let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()

            borderLayer.frame = self.bounds;
            borderLayer.path  = maskPath.cgPath;
            borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth ?? 0;
            borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor?.cgColor;
            borderLayer.fillColor   = UIColor.clear.cgColor;
            borderLayer.name = "borderLayer"

            self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer);

        }

    }
}
```

Next, add a `UIButton` subclass:

```
class RoundedButton: UIButton {

    var corners: UIRectCorner?
    var radius = CGFloat(0.0)
    var borderWidth = CGFloat(0.0)
    var borderColor: UIColor?

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        super.layoutSubviews()

        // don't apply mask if corners is not set, or if radius is Zero
        guard let _corners = corners, radius > 0.0 else {
            return
        }

        roundCorners(corners: _corners, radius: radius, borderWidth: borderWidth, borderColor: borderColor)

    }

}
```

This gives you a couple benefits: 1) It will update its mask layer frame when the button frame changes (rotating the device, for example), and 2) you could set these values either from your custom cell class **or** from cellForRowAt.

Either way, change your `btnStatus` class from `UIButton` to `RoundedButton` - both in your storyboard and the `@IBOutlet` connection.

Then change your `CustomTableViewCell` to this:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnStatus: RoundedButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // set up corner maskign
        btnStatus.corners = .bottomRight
        btnStatus.radius = 7.0

        // set if desired
//      btnStatus.borderWidth = 2.0
//      btnStatus.borderColor = .blue

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

And finally, your `cellForRowAt` function becomes:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

That should do it...

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your code.  The problem is that your `roundCorners` function is depending on your view's bounds to set your layer's properties and you are calling `roundCorners` in `awakeFromNib` at which point your cell has the same bounds as in the NIB file because autolayout has not been calculated yet.  You need to move your `roundCorners` call into [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews), so it gets called after autolayout is done computing your bounds.

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnStatus: UIButton!    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
                self.btnStatus.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomRight], radius: 7.0, borderWidth: nil, borderColor: nil)
    }
}
```

EDIT also add cell.setNeedsLayout() to cellforRowAt to force layoutSubviews to be called before the cell is drawn for the first time.

Comment: same problem :(

Comment: I am running it and its working.  Did you move the code correctly?

Comment: yes, which simulator, I was checking in iphone7, iOS11, if you can upload zip would nice I'll just run and compare

Comment: its correct on iphone 7 iOS11.  See edited answer for the whole file.

Comment: It is same also on real device, actually if I scroll it fixes the problem, but only if cell rendered again

Comment: then there is something else going on.  Add setNeedsLayout to your cell in cellForRowAt.  this will force layoutSubViews to be called before the cell is drawn for the first time.

Comment: cell.layoutIfNeeded()
cell.setNeedsLayout()
those 2 helped :), please add it to answer I'll accept it, thanks man!

Comment: Just a last comment :), no need to round in layoutSubviews() method :)

Comment: You might atill need it if the cell size changes; for instance auto rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your button is overlapping since it doesn't have an upper constraint? Try adding a bright border and see if you can see the top part, if not try adding a constraint to the top. Also, instead of giving it a static height, try making it a proportional height to the object above it (maybe the screen size of your device is causing it to overlap)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/751wo3hsesjxj6l/AAA3oJyPSVFQ3PZcvRTRPE-Sa?dl=0
It didn't helped