# Image from cell is not sized correctly if masked is applied?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm coding a tableview cell with picture in each cell.
The width of the picture is supposed to be the same that the description under.
It's working perfectly on iphone 6 but not for iphone 5s or iphone 6plus for example...
The problem is here ONLY when I use this function:

```
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.picStep.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8.0, height: 0.0))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
cell.picStep.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

[image]

If I don't have the mask, it's okay:
[image]

How could I keep the radius effet (only on top) and have a good width at the same time ?

I tried to move the "mask function" into the cell directly, in awakeFromNib, in layoutSubviews, of even in the tableViewController, nothing is working :/

---

SOLUTION FOUND:

In my TableViewController I have a little function with constraints:

```
if (indexPath.row + 1) % 2 == 0 {
     cell.constLView1.constant = 60
     cell.constRView1.constant = 15
} else {
     cell.constLView1.constant = 15
     cell.constRView1.constant = 60
}
```

I change the way to get the roundedRect, by calling :

```
roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width - self.constLView1.constant - self.constRView1.constant, height: width - self.constLView1.constant - self.constRView1.constant
```

In the layoutSubviews() of the cell. 
I don't know if it's a good way to do that but it's working ...

Comment: Try to print  `cell.picStep.bounds` what it shows

Comment: Actually your code has not problem and you have also tried in  layoutSubviews this should work well.

Comment: If it is working in some device and not in some devices . may be you have issues with constraint

Comment: @JonSnow I've found a solution, I don't know if it's a good way to do that but it's working ... I edited my first post

Comment: as @DonMag mentioned here his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47534892/3266248